# SaveSentMessageFolder to network folder (and not Outlook folder)

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I'm trying to develop a program that when the user sends an email, it is intercepted using OnItemSend.  This works, however I'm unable to get the next to work which is, after the email is sent, the sent item is saved to a network folder.

I can use the following code to determine a different 'sent folder' called 'TESTER' but i need it to actually be save to a folder path instead or as well as, such as 'c:\temp\email.msg'

```
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim mpf As Outlook.Folder
    mpfInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    mpf = mpfInbox.Folders("TESTER")
    myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    myItem.SaveSentMessageFolder = mpf
```

I know i can do something like...

'myItem.SaveAs sourcefolder & "\" & sName, olMSG'

but it saves it before it is sent so the msg file looks like a saved new email, rather than a saved sent email.

Answer (score 1):

Use The `Items.ItemAdd` event on your custom Outlook folder (it will fire after the message is sent and moved to that folder), save that message (`MailItem.SaveAs`), then delete the original message.

Comment: Many Thanks - Found a great article too after your help: https://jwcooney.com/2012/03/05/vs2010-outlook-thisaddin-how-to-get-the-sent-email-message/